# Autohotkey: multiple / contingent uses for one command

Tags: syntax, automation, autohotkey

I'm working on a game design / UI project to redesign an existing game's control scheme (in this case, Trine) to use minimalistic input.  I am trying to map lateral movement and the jump function to a Win8 tablet's volume buttons.  Here is the basic code I am using:

```
Volume_Up::
Loop 5
{
  Send {right down}
  Sleep 50
}
Send {right up}
Return

Volume_Down::
Loop 5
{
  Send {left down}
  Sleep 50
}
Send {left up}
Return
```

This is working fairly well and is pretty responsive for moving left and right.  However, the desired behavior that I want is to trigger jump (i.e. up) when BOTH buttons are depressed.  For instance:

- Player holds VolumeUp to move right.
- Player comes to an obstacle.
- Player continues to hold VolumeUp to queue right-bound movement and;
- Player taps VolumeDown momentarily
- Player jumps, movement continues up-and-over obstacle toward the right.

I have tried various permutations on using another script with the (Volume_Up & Volume_Down::) syntax to trigger this interaction, but that always seems to interfere with the movement commands. I think this may call for a nested If statement inside the move-left / move-right commands, to check if both buttons are depressed, but the Autohotkey documentation is not very clear and I'm unsure how to code that (I'm more of a game designer than I am a programmer).  Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why are you sending {RIGHT down} five times in a row without releasing it? At least theoretically, it seems illogical to press a key that is already down. Anyway, did you have a look at [GetKeyState](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm)? In each loop run, you could check, if `VolumeDown` is pressed: `if( GetKeyState("Volume_Down", "P") ) ...`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give attention to the comment from MCL. Pressing a button down 5 times and never releasing it in between does not seem to do much.

I think that you want multiple threads to be able to run at the same time.
Look up threads, but be aware about the following:

*"Although AutoHotkey doesn't actually use multiple threads, it simulates some of that behavior: If a second thread is started -- such as by pressing another hotkey while the previous is still running -- the current thread will be interrupted (temporarily halted) to allow the new thread to become current. If a third thread is started while the second is still running, both the second and first will be in a dormant state, and so on."*